# React + $ npm start ==> throwing the error : opensslErrorStack with error code: 'ERR_OSSL_EVP_UNSUPPORTED'/

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm, localhost

$npm start ===> throwing this error: opensslErrorStack: [ 'error:03000086:digital envelope routines::initialization error' ],
library: 'digital envelope routines',
reason: 'unsupported',
code: 'ERR_OSSL_EVP_UNSUPPORTED'

Answer (score 0):

Solution:
On Ubuntu:

Step1: $ export NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider

Step2: $ npm start

Thats all.